# unable to run script on dynamically json parsed content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to give a high level explanation of what's my issue because I can't put up complete code which is too complex.

I have a button. when I click on the button, it pulls data from fb parses it and adds it to the page. Now after it is loaded to then page.. I want to run a script on the loaded content. I am running the script after the data is parsed but somehow it shows that element is not loaded by the time script started running. can some one throw some light.

```
$("somebutton").on("click",function(){
    LoadAndParseFbData();
});

function LoadAndParseFbData(){
    //loaded the json, parsed it and added to the page.
     anotherScript();
}

function anotherScript(){
    // this has some script related to data which is loaded dynamically by parsing json.
}
```

This is what i am trying on high level. please help thanks :)

Comment: Make sure `anotherScript` is really run after the content was loaded. I assume you load the data via Ajax, so the function call has to go in the Ajax success handler.

Comment: thats an FB.api call from where I am parsing the json content and adding it to the page. but I want to know if there is way to make the script run only after the data is parsed and completely loaded on page. anotherScript returns length of the elements added as 0. which means it was unable to find content when the script started running.

Comment: *" I want to know if there is way to make the script run only after the data is parsed and completely loaded on page"*: As I said, call the function from withing the FB API callback.

Comment: you could try running `anotherScript()` from within the ajax success function ;) otherwise what is happening is `anotherScript()` fires immediately after calling the ajax (and before the result comes back)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("somebutton").on("click",function()
    LoadAndParseFbData();
});

function LoadAndParseFbData(){  
    FB.api(path, method, params, function(){
        //loaded the json, parsed it and added to the page.
        anotherScript();
     });         
}

function anotherScript(){
    // this has some script related to data which is loaded dynamically by parsing json.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `anotherScript()` from within the ajax success callback:

```
$J.ajax({
    url: url2, 
    type: "post",
    data: { data: "yourdata",  },
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        anotherScript();
    }, 
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        /*error handling code here*/
    }
});
```

Comment: sorry I am talking about FB.api call..anyways in the above comments by @Felix Kling answered it